# Ruby on Rails: Check whether a word is matched to any attributes in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I am doing my Ruby on Rails project now. PostgreSQL is used as database.I have a table called pets, where stores all pets information(name, gender, age, etc.), which are shown as follows.

{Pet id: 1, name: "Jean", gender: "Female", pet_type: "Cat", age: "0", body_weight: 1, breed: "Abyssinian", created_at: "2015-04-26 23:50:01", updated_at: "2015-04-26 23:50:01"}

{Pet id: 2, ...}

...

{Pet id: 10, ...}

Now I am going to check whether there is a Abyssinian breed cat in table pets. If there is, return the Pet id, otherwise return "no such cat found".

Is there anyone know how to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I tried @infused answer, output = Pet.find_by(breed: "Abyssinian", pet_type: "Cat") || "no such cat found". It will return the first pet where breed == "Abyssinian".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find the first pet where breed == "Abyssinian":

```
pet = Pet.find_by(breed: "Abyssinian", pet_type: "Cat")
```

So, to combine that with your required logic:

```
pet = Pet.find_by(breed: "Abyssinian", pet_type: "Cat")
output = pet ? pet : "no such cat found"
```

You could simply this even further to:

```
output = Pet.find_by(breed: "Abyssinian", pet_type: "Cat") || "no such cat found"
```

Comment: you miss `pet_type: "cat"` I thik

Comment: Thanks @infused! I tried it and it works! I was wondering what I should do to get all pets whose breed is Abyssinian rather than the first pet?

Comment: To find them all use: `Pet.where(breed: "Abyssinian", pet_type: "Cat")`

Answer (score 0):

Is "breed" a field in the pets table? If so, you could do something like:

```
if Pet.exists?( breed: "Abyssinian" )
  x = Pet.where( breed: "Abyssinian" )
else
  x = "No such cat found"
end
```

The danger in this is that there could be multiple Pets returned. If you want to find one and only one, you could do

```
if Pet.where( breed: "Abyssinian" ).count == 1
```

instead.

**REVISION**

@infused's answer is more succinct, I would encourage an implementation similar to his, assuming a breed column exists.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt answer! Breed is a field in the pets table. I was wondering whether there is a way to return all pets id whose breed is Abyssinian?